# Outputs of "ls *" are inconsistent

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ls

Just confused about the outputs of command "ls *". I tested below scenario both in Ubuntu 11.10 and Redhat Enterprise 6.3, got the same results.

**Shell log**

```
$ uname -a
   Linux 2.6.32-279.19.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat Nov 24 14:35:28 EST 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ echo $0
   -bash
$ cd test
$ ls
$ ls *             *<== at first, no file/directory under current work directory*
ls: cannot access *: No such file or directory
$ mkdir abc        *<== create a new directory "abc"*
$ ls *             *<== output of "ls *" is empty but directory "abc" has been created.*
$ mkdir abcd       *<== create the second directory "abcd"*
$ ls *             *<== at this point, all the directories("abc" and "abcd") are displayed.*
abc:

abcd:
```

Can anyone explain why output of "ls *" is empty after directory "abc" created? Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

That's mainly because the glob pattern is expanded by the shell, not by `ls` itself.

Therefore, after creating an empty `abc` directory, issuing:

```
$ ls *
```

Results in `ls` being invoked as if you typed:

```
$ ls abc
```

Which lists the contents of `abc`. Since `abc` is empty, nothing is printed.

In the same way, after creating `abcd`, issuing:

```
$ ls *
```

Results in `ls` being invoked as if you typed:

```
$ ls abc abcd
```

And since two directories are passed, `ls` will print each of them as a header before listing their (empty) contents.

Answer (score 6):

Because `ls *` is printing content of the directory `abcd` which is empty hence you don't see anything in the output. `ls *` prints all the files and **content of all the directories** in current directory.

Try this `ls` command instead:

```
ls -d *
```

which will show `abcd` in output.

from `man ls`

```
-d      Directories are listed as plain files (not searched recursively).
```

Answer (score 6):

This does not answer your question, but addresses the `*: no such file` error.

When the bash shell option `nullglob` is unset, if a wildcard expands to *no files*, then the wildcard is taken literally by the shell as a plain string.

```
$ ls
$ ls *
ls: cannot access *: No such file or directory
```

There are no files, so the shell treats <kbd>*</kbd> as a plain string.

Turn on the `nullglob` option and the shell will substitute the wildcard with nothing:

```
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ ls *
$
```